# Force Highest Thumbnail Quality for Youtube Videos

Tags: javascript, html, regex, innerhtml

I'm trying to make a custom JS for my Wordpress to force Highest Quality Thumbnails for Youtube videos.

I found the Regex : `https:\/\/i.ytimg.com\/vi\/(?:.+).jpg$`

The example url should go from

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/***/hqdefault.jpg
```

To

```
https://i.ytimg.com/vi/***/maxresdefault.jpg
```

So the script needs to follow these steps:

1- Find all the Youtube Thumbnails (Regex Matching)
2- Replace `hqdefault.jpg` with `maxresdefault.jpg` and apply the change to the HTML

I tried for +24hours, but couldn't get the puzzle together... Thank you for helping out !

Comment: Maybe you should be clearer in your question what you want to do. Apparently you are trying to replace youtube thumbnails inside embedded iframes: that's a CORS policy violation it's not possible.

Comment: Alright, didn't know that it's a policy violation, is there a way to get it "legally" thanks to the embed code ?
Thank you for your patience

Answer (score 0):

I edited for all the images of the page:

```js
const regex = /[a-z]*.jpg$/g;
var x = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
var i;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
  x[i].src = x[i].src.replace(regex, 'maxresdefault.jpg');
 }
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick answer, but the script needs to apply to any image (in all pages) matching the Regex, so the Thumbnail URL should be a variable, and that's what I'm struggling with.

Comment: Almost there, you're replacing every JPG, I just need the Youtube Thumbnails...
You're also missing a document.write to actually apply the changes.
Thanks for your help and reactivity :)

Comment: Not sure why `document.write` is needed: the question updates the 'src' attribute and should cause the image to be reloaded with the new source.

Comment: @Terry You're right, the replacement would be enough